# Expandable list view on group expand, change the image of expanded group

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to change the image on the group on clicking a particular group.
i had created my own custom base adapter to inflate expandable list.
And inside `getGroupView` i have the following code to change the image on expanded group.
But on expansion the image is changing in groups which are not expanded.

Is there any solution for this?

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, 
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView categoryImage = (ImageView)  
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.menu_category_image);
    category.setText(subItems.get(groupPosition).getCategoryName());
    if(isExpanded) {
        categoryImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dn_arrow);
    } else 
        categoryImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.right_arrow);
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_group_indicator))
       .setImageResource(isExpanded?R.drawable.arrowup:R.drawable.arrowdown);
```

Comment: Great solution! Just put it inside `getGroupView()` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
list.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() 
{
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,  int groupPosition, long id) 
            {
    //do your stuff here           
                 return false;
           }
        }
   });
```

For more information try below links, here you will have some information.............

http://qtcstation.com/2011/03/working-with-the-expandablelistview-part-1/

OR

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html

OR

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/10/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/

This may help you..........